# Wagtail set additional permissions for MyPage

Tags: permissions, wagtail

Wagtail newbie here.

I am trying to add some additional permissions to specific models, but nothing shows up into the "wagtail admin". I can do this the "django" way but I have the impression that wagtail could handle this type of permissions. I could not find any hints in the wagtail documentation.

I have a new model named "MyPage":

```
class MyPage(Page):
    [...]

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
        ('view_restricted_document', 'can view restricted documents'),
    )
```

How do I make this permission available in the groups section of the wagtail admin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that there is a wagtail hook which does just that: "register_permsissions".

Create a file named "wagtail_hooks.py" if it does not exist in your app and enter the following:

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore import hooks
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

@hooks.register('register_permissions')
def view_restricted_page():
    return Permission.objects.filter(codename="view_restricted_document")
```

That's it.
Now if I browse the groups section, under "Other Permissions" I can view the additional option "can view restricted document".