# How can I efficiently restrict a non-CMS page view to a user group in wagtail with 'permissions_required' hook?

Tags: wagtail

I have an app within my wagtail site which uses several pages constructed in views.py (here because they contain complex-ish processing of forms and data and do not need any CMS functionality). One of these views, I want to restrict to users of a specific group.

For other pages, I use a `@logon required` mixin, which works fine. I can write some code which uses something like `def has_group(user, group_name):
    return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()`, but this seems messy when wagtail has a nice built in permissions model. Therefore, I am trying to use the following hook in wagtail_hook.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from wagtail.core import hooks

@hooks.register('register_permissions')
def view_committee_page():
    return Permission.objects.filter(codename="view_committee_page")
```

This isn't showing up in wagtail admin under group object permissions as I believe it should.
My understanding is only based on the odd example I've found using Wagtail v1.X. The documentation is vague on this specific hook: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/reference/hooks.html#register-permissions

The only modification I've made to the examples I've seen (eg. here: [Wagtail set additional permissions for MyPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663893/wagtail-set-additional-permissions-for-mypage) ) is to update `wagtail.wagtailcore` to `wagtail.core` as per 2.0 release notes.

I know my wagtail_hooks.py file is being picked up correctly as I have another hook in there working as expected.

Am I missing something? Is there a more up to date way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating your own function with the decorator: 
`@hooks.register('before_serve_page')`

in watail_hooks.py there is a function called check_view_restrictions() so you could do something similar to this?

Comment: I could use `@hooks.register('before_serve_page')` and create a function, but does this yield any benefit over creating the `has_group(user, group_name)` function in views.py? Also, I can't find any documentation on check_view_restrictions - could you clarify please?

Answer (score 0):

You would also need to set the permissions on your `Page` model.

```
from wagtail.core.models import Page

class MyPage(Page):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (("page_view_only", "Can view my pages"),)
```

Then use the hook in `wagtail_hooks.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from wagtail.core import hooks

@hooks.register('register_permissions')
def page_view_only():
    return Permission.objects.filter(codename="page_view_only")
```

There should be a new permission available in the admin `Group` settings.